# How to create a column shortcode in footer of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to separate the three columns and each column having five rows in footer area of my wordpress site.. I don't know how to use short code for that.. Can anyone help me..

[image]

For example Like this footer I need using shortcode..

Comment: Why don't you register a widget for it? You can use divs to differentiate every row using div. You can then easily add rows using widget located under appearance to add one or more rows.

Comment: I want to fix a contact form also in my footer.. So I need to write code for that. Thats why I need short code

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending to do it using a shortcode then use the following code to create it;

```
`<?php
function firstshortcode_function() {
  *//Your Code Should Be Written Here!*
  return 'My first shortcode';
}
add_shortcode('firstshortcode', 'firstshortcode_function');
?>`
```

.. and use this [firstshortcode] shortcode wherever you would like to call it.

Note: You can replace the function name with anything you like and replace the shortcode appropriately.

To add HTML content under it, use the following code;

```
    <?php
function my_custom_shortcode( $atts ) {

 / Turn on buffering /
 ob_start(); ?>

<div>
  // YOUR HTML CODE GOES HERE
  <h1>Test</h1>
  <p>My content</p>
  </div>

<?php
 / Get the buffered content into a var /
 $sc = ob_get_contents();

 / Clean buffer /
 ob_end_clean();

 / Return the content as usual /
 return $sc;

}
add_shortcode( 'shortcode', 'my_custom_shortcode' );
?>
```

Comment: For example, Can u add some code for How to write between that function?

Comment: editing the above answer window, have a look at it, please. But it is preferable to use widgets instead of using these short codes, you can even place shortcodes under widgets and easily integrate any form's shortcode.

Comment: Sorry, still I confused.. Can u say with one example(column)